# Laravel 5.3, queries on Models. Is this a good pratice?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

It's a good pratice put methods in models that execute SQL Queries?

Example: My app has OrderController, Order (Model) and the route app/order/{order}/disable that calls OrderController@disable()

Which of these codes are the best in this situation?

ex 1:

```
../OrderController

public function disable($id) {
   $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
   $order->disable();

   return view('order.index'); 
}


../Order

public function disable() {
    $this->status = 0;
    $this->save();
}
```

ex 2:

```
../OrderController

public function disable($id) {
   $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
   $order->status = 0;
   $order->save();

   return view('order.index'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
Order::findOrFail($id)->update(['status ', 0]);
```

if you need to do some processing on the model data before saving, you can create `Repository` for that, so the controller and the model will stay clean

Comment: Suppose the Order has 3 models that disable in cascade with it. For every object I will execute that statement?

Comment: you can make a `OrderRepository` .. in controller you call `OrderRepository->disable($orderId);` and in OrderRepository you can cal the `Order::findOrFail($id)->update(['status ', 0]);` and any other cascading..etc